# How to get json name values on iteration instead of indexes or ids?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coffeescript

I have the following json:

```
var testjson = {
    "Mytest": [{
        "Testing": {
            "static": {
                "name": "first name"
            },
            "key1": "key1 val",
            "key2": 10

        }
    }, {
        "Testing": {
            "static": {
                "name": "second name"
            },
            "key3": 20,
            "key4": true


        }
    }, {
        "Testing": {
            "static": {
                "name": "third name"
            },
            "key5": "key5 val"

        }
    }]
}
```

I have the following coffeescript: @`itemNames = (item for item of @mydata).sort (a,b) -> a>b`  , but I changed it to the following javascript conversion:

```
var mydata = testjson.Mytest;
var item;

this.itemNames = ((function() {
  var results;
  results = [];
  for (item in mydata) {
    results.push(item);
  }
  return results;
}).call(this)).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a > b;
});
console.log(mydata);//gives: [Object, Object, Object] 
console.log(this.itemNames);//gives: ["0", "1", "2"], but I need it like: ["first name", "second name", "third name"], how can I get it ?
```

Here I am getting the output in my console as: `["0", "1", "2"]`, but I need it like: `["first name", "second name", "third name"]`, and of course if I expand it on the console, it should display those values(like: `0: "first name", 1: "second name", 2: "third name"`). Created [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/zg4qdepf/1/).

Please, help me that how to get those names and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.Your item is the index of the element.Your need to get the element at the index, then access to property `name` via `Testing.static.name`.

```
this.itemNames = ((function() {
  var results;
  results = [];
  for (item in mydata) {
    results.push(mydata[item].Testing.static.name);
  }
  return results;
}).call(this)).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a > b;
});
```

This is the code.

```js
var testjson = {
    "Mytest": [{
        "Testing": {
            "static": {
                "name": "first name"
            },
            "key1": "key1 val",
            "key2": 10

        }
    }, {
        "Testing": {
            "static": {
                "name": "second name"
            },
            "key3": 20,
            "key4": true


        }
    }, {
        "Testing": {
            "static": {
                "name": "third name"
            },
            "key5": "key5 val"

        }
    }]
};


var mydata = testjson.Mytest;
var item;

this.itemNames = ((function() {
  var results;
  results = [];
  for (item in mydata) {
    results.push(mydata[item].Testing.static.name);
  }
  return results;
}).call(this)).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a > b;
});

console.log(this.itemNames);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes this is what I am looking for ! Thanks for help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple solution...

```
var mydata = testJSON.Mytest;
var nameArray = [];
var nameMap= {};
var count =0;
$.each(mydata , function(i , data)
{
    var data1 = data.Testing

    var name = data1.static.name
    nameArray.push(name);
    nameMap[count] = name;
    count ++;
});

console.log(nameArray);
console.log(nameMap);
```